# Jupyter: Python input is intermittently not appearing in For Loop

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, input, jupyter-notebook

I'm writing a script to cycle through data where most entries can be handled automatically, however in some instances a human may need to input a decision.

The purpose is to map together two datasets where there is potential for multiple matches, if there are multiple matches I can decide which to use based on the name and level 2 name.

```
i = 1
main_secondary_map = {}

for index, row in df_main():
    id = row['id']
    print(row[['id','name']].values)
    df = df_secondary[df_secondary['id'] == id][['Secondary ID','Name','Level 2 Name']].drop_duplicates()
    print(df)

    print(i)
    (time.sleep(.02)) 

    if len(df) == 0:
        secondary_id = 0
    elif len(df) == 1:
        secondary_id = df.iloc[0,0]
    else:
        secondary_id = input('Secondary ID:')
    (time.sleep(.02)) 
    main_secondary_map[id] = secondary_id

    clear_output(wait=True)


    (time.sleep(.02)) 
    i += 1
```

The problem is when this code runs it will go through a bunch of times (the number of successful times varies, seemingly randomly), then it will get stuck before displaying the input.

I've inserted the small delay based on a response about ordering but this hasn't helped.

Any ideas why the input sometimes doesn't show?

Comment: Have you tried running it without `clear_output(wait=True)`?

Comment: This appears to have fixed it, thank you